# Creating heaps dynamically in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap

I've got a problem with implementing heaps as data structures. My task is to create initially unknown amount of heaps of also initially unknown sizes on which I'll be able to work later on. The number of binary heaps as well as their sizes will be given as a parameters (some stdin data), so the `for` loop should be suitable. In addition, I've got to be as little object-oriented as possible, as it's a part of an algorithmic classes problem...

However, I don't know where to start because I've got no clue how to refer to them (by name?) and how to store them.

Comment: any dynamic memory allocation using new operator allocates memory from heap area. So, you may have your own class to encapsulate the structure and behavior and then issue suitable new to allocate objects of your class type.

Comment: I think he is talking about binary heaps as data structures.

Comment: `std::vector<std::priority_queue<T> >` gives you a resizable array of binary heaps holding elements of type `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
struct Heap
{  
int *arr;
int count;  //number of elements in heap
int capacity;  //size of heap;
int heap_type;  //min(0) or max(1)
};
```

Then You can define the heap, dynamically allocate it using new/malloc and initialize all four members.

Note: you have to do two dynamic allocations one for heap and other for array arr .

Comment: Thank U! But what did you mean by heap_type field? And one more question regarding *arr. I'm sure this is the array where all the exact values are going to be stored so why inside of the struture there is just *arr and not something like int *arr = new int[capacity]; wouldn't it be valid?

Comment: @vladimir1923 heap_type is to make this representation more general, heap can be of two types min heap or max heap and no we can't use that because when you create an object of type struct heap, capacity is still unknown, so *arr can only be allocated after we initialize capacity.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know where to start because I've got no clue how to refer to them (by name?) and how to store them, so I'll be very grateful for any help from You Guys.

Consider creating a class for a heap (by heap I mean a binary heap). You should make this class a semi-regular type (copyable, movable, equally comparable). Then, store n instances of your class in a std::vector.

Comment: Maybe what about a structure called Heap which would represent na object of this type which then could be created dynamically and allocated in a dynamic array a size of which is one of the parameters?

Comment: If you create a dynamic array, you perform the same operations that a `std::vector` does - or similar (vector covers them in a layer of abstraction, making them safer). Allocating a dynamic array or using a vector, are both valid solutions for this.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `std::priority_queue` already provides a binary heap implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got no clue how to refer to them (by name?)

You can have an array of heaps and refer to them by their index

> and how to store them

A heap is stored as a flat array of data. The children of node with index `i` are nodes with indices `2*i` and `2*i+1`

Comment: Yeap, thank U, I've came up with this idea, but my problem is, sadly, a bit more technical, since I think can describe this problem by words, but it seems a bit complicated for me to write a code structure...

Comment: I think clearly describing the problem by words is the most difficult part which already splits up the problem in more manageable pieces.

Comment: @stefaanv Maybe You're right. :)